# ios App Disclaimer

Tags: ios, eula

I am writing an application for iPhone and had some questions regarding eula :-

1. If I do not include any disclaimer/ eula in my app, then would Apple's standard EULA 
   http://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/appstore/dev/stdeula/
   automatically apply to my app ?
2. If I include a small disclaimer inside my application (as a popup on initial screen), then would Apple's EULA still cover my app ?
3. I tried downloading few apps on my ipad and did not see Apple's standard EULA. So, where can I actually see the EULA before downloading something ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing rather than programming.


Comment: sorry. I am not familiar with how the eula process for ios app goes. So, this question can be considered to be related to app submission

Comment: This question is off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you decide your EULA when you submit you application to the iTunes Store. At submission time you can choose a custom one, or if you don't provide it, the Apple EULA is chosen by default.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So, if I include any disclaimer also inside my app, then can I still use Apple's EULA ?

Comment: Yes, you'll be able to do that.